# Changing Font for specific texts in the App by User Settings

Tags: java, android-studio, fonts, settings

I'm working on a Japanese Vocabulary App in Android Studio in Java. 
I want to make it possible for the user to select a Font that best fits there preferences.

Currently, I have a Font added to res and defined a font family using the font file. All japanese text (Textbox, Buttons etc.) in the App uses this font family.

Is there a way to change the font family itself or change the font family tag-value pair in xml for every element using this font family while the app is running.

This is my current font family definition

```
<font-family xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <font app:fontStyle="normal" app:fontWeight="400" app:font="@font/kosugimaru_regular"/>
    <font app:fontStyle="italic" app:fontWeight="400" app:font="@font/kosugimaru_regular" />
</font-family>
```

And this is how i use this font family in xml:

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TV_KanjiChar"
        android:fontFamily="@font/kanji_default"
        android:text="学"
        android:textSize="60sp" 
        ...
        />
```

if there is no way of changing that binding while running the app is there another elegant way of solving this problem? I Would like to avoid using update functions in every activity to change the font family dynamically onCreate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going ahead and answer my question.

A quite elegant solution is to create a subclass of Textview and Button and add a UpdateFont function to the constructors.

```
public class KanjiTextView extends AppCompatTextView {
    public KanjiTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        updateFont();
    }

    public KanjiTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        updateFont();
    }

    public KanjiTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        updateFont();

    }

    public void updateFont()
    {
        int font_res = get_user_selected_font();

        Typeface typeface = getFont(getContext(), font_res.get_Res());
        setTypeface(typeface);
    }
}

_____________________________________________________________________________


      <com.[package].KanjiTextView
            android:id="@+id/TV_Kanjitext"
            android:text="学校"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            ...
            />
```